# Unnecessary extra input lines

Tags: c#

I am making an app that based on the input of one of player1 it creates a new number based on difficulty.
When I input the number, the app asks for number I entered+ more to display and I don't want that. Example:

If I input 4, the app will ask for 4 other inputs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD2zQ.png

I don't want this to happen can anyone explain why and how to fix this?

Here is my main code.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Can {user[0]} select a level? If not choosen between either 30 seconds or between 1, 2, 3  it will be automatically choosen.");
Level_Select level = new Level_Select(LevelSelect());

static int LevelSelect()
   {
    int select;
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out select);
    return select;
   }

if (LevelSelect() == 1)
   {
     Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level1()}");
   }
   else if (LevelSelect() == 2)
   {
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level2()}");
   }
    else if (LevelSelect() == 3)
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level3()}");
    }
    else if ((LevelSelect() != 1) || (LevelSelect() != 2) || (LevelSelect() != 3))
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.Default()}");
    }
```

And this is my Level Difficulty Class.

```
class Level_Select
{
  private int level;

  public Level_Select(int level)
  {
  this.Level = level;
  }

   public int Level
   {
    get { return level; }
    set {
     if (value == 1)
      {
      this.level = value;
      }
      else if (value == 2)
      {
      this.level = value;
      }
      else if (value == 3)
      {
      this.level = value;
      }
     }
    }

    public static int Default()
    {
    int min = 000;
    int max = 999;
    Random num = new Random();
    return num.Next(min, max);
    }

    public static int level1()
    {
    int min = 000;
    int max = 99999;
    Random num = new Random();
    return num.Next(min, max);
    }

   public static int level2()
   {
   int min = 00000;
   int max = 99999999;
   Random num = new Random();
   return num.Next(min, max);
   }

   public static int level3()
   {
   int min = 000000000;
   long ten = 9999999999;
   int max = (int)ten;
   Random num = new Random();
   return num.Next(min, max);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in your if else chain. When you put:

```
if (LevelSelect() == 1)                             // POINT A
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level1()}");
}
else if (LevelSelect() == 2)                        // POINT B
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level2()}");
}
```

At POINT A, you call `LevelSelect()`, which prompts for input. If this returns anything but 1, the if fails, meaning you move on to POINT B, which calls `LevelSelect()` *again* and so prompts you again, and so on, every time you call `LevelSelect()`.

What you probably want is:

```
int selectedLevel = LevelSelect(); // Called only once

Level_Select level = new Level_Select(selectedLevel);

if (selectedLevel  == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level1()}");
}
else if (selectedLevel  == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level2()}");
}
else if (selectedLevel  == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level3()}");
}
else    // No need to retest; if it's here it's not 1, 2 or 3
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.Default()}");
}
```

Though in fact, a `switch` is better in these cases:

```
int selectedLevel = LevelSelect();   // Called only once

Level_Select level = new Level_Select(selectedLevel);

switch (selectedLevel)  
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level1()}");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level2()}");
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.level2()}");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine($"{Level_Select.Default()}");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Solution: call LevelSelect *once* and store the result. Then check that result in your if-chain.

Comment: Your code will ask for input twice. I posted a solution below.

Comment: @Anouar I don't understand. Where does my code ask for a second input?

Comment: @Jasper Kent you edited the answer when I was posting my comment. In your 1st solution you wrote `if (LevelSelect().. else if (LevelSelect()))`

Comment: @Anouar, no, that wasn't my solution. That was me quoting the original code, so as to explain the problem.

Comment: I see...I used this code and it appears that when I input the number 4 it will ask for a readline ONLY once.

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/c324c69877a730feb9492d6f75f31e6f

Comment: @Dash I'm not sure I understand. Is it now behaving how you want? If not, could you be clear about the behaviour you do want?

Comment: @Dash I just noticed I'd missed your original duplicate call to `LevelSelect()`. I've tidied that up.

Comment: @Jasper Kent It's not exactly behaving how I want it to behave. I want it ask for only ONE input and then it calls the number generator method from the other class based on that single input. The code you have provided is asking for only TWO inputs, upon the 2nd input the method is called. 

I want it to ask for ONE input and that ONE input is what calls either methods from the Level_Select Class. Hope I was clear enough I'm quite new to forums.

Comment: @Dash Did my edit fix it? Simply put, you will get an input every time you call `LevelSelect()`. If you only want one input, only call it once.

Comment: @Jasper Kent Your edit didn't solve it completley as it is asking for an input twice. But it's better than entering 8 and it asks for an input 8 times. 

Also sorry for the hour late answer.

Comment: @Dash If you're still having, put a breakpoint on the line `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out select);` Then you'll be able to see the two places you're calling it from and remove on of them.

Comment: @Jasper Kent I found the issue, it was me being _half blind_ as there was a ReadLine under the `Console.WriteLine($"\nCan {user[0]} select a level? If not choosen between either 30 seconds or between 1, 2, 3  it will be automatically choosen.");` statement. 

I removed that and it worked properly!

So the issue was having a duplicate Readline. Other than that at least I learned new statement ways from you and the answer beneath me, including a new syntax which is the `switch` syntax!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `LevelSelect()` on each **if** statement so it's normal that it will make a `Console.ReadLine()` each time. You should call that method only once:

```
var selectedLevel = LevelSelect();

var level = new Level_Select(selectedLevel);

if (selectedLevel == 1)
{
    //do some stuff
    Level_Select.level1();
}
else if (selectedLevel == 2)
{
    // do some other stuff
    Level_Select.level2();
}
```

And so on.

Comment: This delivers the same output as the answer above, it asks for the input once more, although it's a massive improvement from the issue I had.
Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/c324c69877a730feb9492d6f75f31e6f

Comment: @Dash if you mean the call to `new Level_Select()` I edited the answer to include it. But the idea of the solution is still the same: Call `LevelSelect()` only once.

Comment: so it's normal that it will ask for Readline another time? There isn't a way to prevent this?